# Debounce with useCallback in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, use-ref, debouncing

I have a function that I'd like to debounce in my React project, using Lodash's debounce library.

The high level structure is like so (greatly simplified for purposes of this question):

1. I have a function that can be called multiple times, but should only trigger `callApiToSavetoDatabase()` once every 3 seconds.

```
const autoSaveThing = useRef(debounce(() => {
    callApiToSaveToDatabase();
}, 3000)).current;
```

2. This API calls an asynchronous function that sets react State and calls an API.

```
const callApiToSaveToDatabase = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log('Started API function');
    setSomeState(true);
    try {
       const response = await apiCall(data);
    } catch {
       // failure handling
    }
}, [ /* some dependencies */ ]);
```

What works:

- `callApiToSavetoDatabase()` is correctly only called once during the debounce period.

What doesn't work:

- We hit the `console.log` line in `callApiToSavetoDatabase()` but from debugging in the browser, the code quits out of `callApiToSavetoDatabase()` as soon as I set state with `setSomeState(true)`.

Is there some limitation with setting state inside a useCallback function I'm hitting here?

It's worth noting that if I call `callApiToSavetoDatabase()` directly it works perfectly.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the snippet especially without seeing the dependency arrays of your hooks (i.e. `callApiToSaveToDatabase = React.useCallback(() => { ... }, [apiCall, ...]`), but my guess is that you may have a chain of dependencies with an unintended side effect somewhere.

Comment: @C.Helling I was hoping that wasn't the answer. There is a handful of dependencies (all the ones my linter recommended) but listing those would probably require sharing the entire source code, which is not reasonable for this post unfortunately. :(

Comment: Are you able to remove `setSomeState` and see if it still works? Perhaps you can follow that train of dependencies all the way through (`someState` triggers this useEffect which then changes the state of...) and see if there's something that affects your useRef or something encompassing the API call? Or you can try to make an MVP and see if that still happens (and is safe to post here). Usually I find that when I make an MVP that it works, which means my issue is usually somewhere between the MVP and my code.

Comment: @C.Helling I figure out my issue, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here ended up being that my `callApiToSaveToDatabase()` function was both:

1. Inside my React component and
2. Also setting React state

This combination cause a component re-render which subsequently halted my function.

The solution here was to move `callApiToSaveToDatabase()` *outside* of the React component, and pass to it all the necessary state variables and setState function references it needed. An example of this is as follows:

```js
// function that calls my API
const callApiToSaveToDatabase = async (someState,setSomeSTate) => {
    setSomeState(true);
    try {
       const response = await apiCall(someState);
    } catch {
       // failure handling
    }
};

// debounce wrapper around the API function above
const autoSaveThing = debounce((someState,setSomeState) => callApiToSaveToDatabase(someState,setSomeState), 3000));

// my React component
const myComponent = () => {
    // some code
    autoSaveThing(someState,setSomeState);
}
```